# Is it possible to make a directory that a user cannot list, but would be able to access files in it?

Tags: permissions, security, users, adduser, user-profile

Is it possible to make a directory that a user cannot list, but would be able to access files in it?

Provide examples of when this might be necessary.

Comment: No it is not and how would they know the file name? Reads like homework suggest you do your own homework.

Comment: @David, that is actually not correct. You could run some software that serves the files, but does not allow listing. Such as a webserver does usually. However, the question should be focused to an actual problem, and not some theoretical question.

Comment: With normal Unix file permissions, unsetting the read bit on the directory will prevent its contents from being listed. See for example [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526315/65304)

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190151/in-linux-how-do-i-set-permissions-for-a-directory-that-prevent-a-user-from-listi

Comment: "Provide examples of when this might be necessary." sorry? why would we need to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed. You can see the contents of the directory if the read `r` permission is set. You can traverse a directory and retrieve a file from it if the `x` permission is set.

Examples where that may be necessary? Any time you want to give users access to a specific folder, but do not want they can inspect the contents of the parent directories. For example, if you do not want that users can see the name of the home directory of other users in `/hom`, then you could turn off the `r` bit of `/home` for "others".

It is never "necessary". It is always the administrator that balances security needs and implements them. There can only be recommendations here, and these will depend on each individual use case.